# In python, is there a static equivalent to isinstance?

Tags: python, inheritance, static, isinstance

I want to scan a module (using `dir()`) and extract all class names (`type` objects) of classes that extend a certain parent class.
Is there any way to do this without first creating instances that I can check with `isinstance()`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)
That was fast

Comment: No problem.  I removed the comment and reposted it as an answer :)

Comment: As a side note, I think I'd use `inspect.getmembers` with `inspect.isclass` instead of `dir` -- Then this becomes a simple list comprehension.  It seems more robust in my mind, but I couldn't give you a reason why ...

Comment: As another note, enforcing a particular type is generally unpythonic - is there a reason you need that and can't just check behaviour without worrying about if it is a subclass? (If so, checking for needed attributes/functions or implementing an ABC with `__subclasshook__()` might be a better idea).

Comment: I have a directory you can drop/drag plugin modules in that can contain one or multiple classes extending `Plugin`. I want to be able to provide a list of all plugins without creating instances and checking their interface. Using `__subclasshook__()` is a good idea, but I'm not sure I see the benefits over just using `issubclass` and normal subclassing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`issubclass`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass)